# is there a dataProviderChange event for dropdownlist?

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, flex4.5, flex-spark

I have a case where the SelectedItem isn't called after the data provider changes for
a dropdownlist.
is there a way to detect if such a change occurred?
Thanks

Comment: What do you mean 'the SelectedItem' isn't called? Please elaborate. Provide code, or a significantly better explanation, and we can help you.

Comment: The selectedIndex setter should always be called and set to -1. The List components have always been a bit buggy with this stuff. (But then again, the dataProvider setter should _also_ be called)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just about every public property in the Flex Framework has a 'propertyChanged' event that is dispatched from the properties set method.  They are used primarily for binding purposes, but not usually formally documented.

The dataProvider set method of a DropDownList does indeed dispatch a dataProviderChanged event.  The code is several layers up in the hierarchy, as part of SkinnableDataContainer or if the skin for your 'SkinnableDataContainer' has a dataGroup it is dispatched from the DataGroup.

But, this event will probably will not be exposed via code hinting in MXML. You'll have to listen for it in ActionScript:

```
myList.addEventListener('dataProviderChanged', onDataProviderChanged);
```

Keep in mind this event will always be dispatched when the dataProvider changes, regardless of what happens to the selectedItem property.

Answer (score 0):

You can listen to changes in the selectedItem in a DropDownList through the [*IndexChangeEvent*](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/spark/events/IndexChangeEvent.html), illustrated by the code below:

```
<s:DropDownList id="dl_mydl"
  dataProvider="{dataProvider}"
  change="dropDownListChangeHandler(event)"
/>

protected function dropDownListChangeHandler(event:IndexChangeEvent) : void
{
 //DO SOMETHING
}
```